# Strange plot with matplotlib on linear regression

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-regression

I have a problem with a simple exercise. I can't understand how to plot the predicted function by the model. It plot a set of lines, like you can see in this image [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh29X.png)

The code is the following:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt

def f(x):
    return np.sin(np.pi * 2 * x) + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(x))

def main():
    NUM_SAMPLES = 15
    x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, NUM_SAMPLES)
    y = f(x)

    plt.plot(x, y, "bo")

    poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
    X = poly.fit_transform(np.array(x).reshape(-1,1))

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)

    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = regr.predict(X_test)

    #X = np.concatenate([X_train, X_test])
    print(regr.coef_)
    plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, "g-")
    plt.show()

    rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
    print("RMSE = %.2f" % rmse)
```

What should I change?
Thanks!

Comment: The first thing to do, is adding the necessary imports to make the example code reproducible.  Also note that `plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, "g-")` connects the points in the order that is given by `X_test`. You might want to sort `X_test` before calculating `y_pred`

Comment: I'll order now X_train, thanks! Yes i already have imports, I only didn't copied them

Comment: Well, you should also order `X_test`. You can edit the post to add the missing imports.